# Are there any nonflammable thermal insulators which can be made at home?

Tags: heat, materials

I am trying to build a homemade thermos. It needs to be able to conserve the heat in 125 ml of water for 15 minutes.

However, unlike a normal thermos, it also needs to be able to be heated. What homemade substances can I use that are not flammable, yet provide a relatively high degree of insulation?

Note that my thermos will be heated with a flame from a candle for 25 minutes.

Comment: Strictly speaking an insulating flask prevents heat moving in either direction. So heating something in the flask will always be very inefficient (the whole point of the flask is to inhibit the flow of heat). In a vacuum thermos (sometimes called a dewar) this will be virtually impossible. You could design a flask that is *mostly* insulated but with a gap where you can heat the internal space. But this makes it a worse insulator.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a ceramic container.  You could adjust the density, thickness, and size to match your insulating requirements.

"home made' is loose, here, since you would need to acquire oven bake-able ceramics, or a similar product.  (unless you have a kiln lying around).